# Liferay view permissions

Tags: permissions, liferay

I have a navigation bar setup in my theme that any user is able to see. I however want to change the navigation bar based on the user's permissions (Include links, exclude others).

How can this be achieved if the navigation bar is "set in stone" in my portal_normal.vm file?

Answer (score 0):

You can archive that setting the permissions of each page. You can set **view** permission to roles for each page. You just have to go Admin->Page and look for **PERMISSION** button, then you can admin visibility for the page that you're editing.

If you do this, the page automatically disappear or not depending the user's roles.

It's required to use the default navigation.vm sintaxis:

```
#foreach ($nav_item in $nav_items)
#end
```

Velocity variable $nav_items has (or has not) items (page links) based on permissions.